# Regex: Select all text from WORD_A

Tags: regex, windows

I have this kind of example:

```
text_1
text_2
text WORD_A
text
...
text text
```

I want to select and delete all text from WORD_A. My desire output will be:

```
text_1
text_2
text
```

I try this regex, but is not working in TextCrawler:

`(?s)(WORD_A).*?[\s\S]`

Comment: Try `WORD_A[\s\S]*`

Comment: Why to use a lazy operator? Just use `(?s)(WORD_A).*`

Comment: One of the above should work unless you are using some tool that needs enabling a multiline mode (like Dngrep)